# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException nvarchar to float

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm updating my table with this code:

```
 private void AddToQuotation()
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(@"update JobQuotations
                                set    quo_discount     = @discount
                                ,      quo_unitPrice   = @unitPrice
                                ,      quo_TotalAmount = @totalAmount
                                ,      quo_finishing   = @finishing
                                where  quo_custname    = @customername
                                and    quo_verified    = 'Yes'", con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customername",DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@discount",txtDisc.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unitPrice",txtUnitPrice.Text);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@finishing",txtFinishing.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalAmount",lblTotalAmount.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        string script = "alert(\"Functioning!\");";

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
            "ServerControlScript", script, true);
    }
```

And I keep getting this error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Error converting data type nvarchar.

This code work for me last time.I didn't know what happened.

Comment: Always convert at clientside, so f.e. with `decimal.Parse`, all the more if you use `AddWithValue` instead of `Add`.

Comment: What are the data types of the columns of JobQuotations?

Comment: something like this?`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@discount",double.Parse(txtDisc.Text));`

Comment: @Lithium discount,uniPrice and Total amount are float data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advice you to use the `SqlDbType` and put for each parameter to the corresponding type in the database like this :

```
cmd.Parameters.Add (new SqlParameter("@unitPrice", SqlDbType.Float).Value = txtUnitPrice.Text ;
```

or

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unitPrice", SqlDbType.Float).Value = txtUnitPrice.Text;
```

Comment: I'm always for explicit type declaration so nothing funny happens. I personally do something that would boil down to: `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@unitPrice", SqlDbType.Float) { Value = Convert.ToDouble(txtUnitPrice.Text);})`

Comment: are you change sysntax for all parameter ?

Comment: should I follow the the first example?with **new**? or the second one?

Comment: now I'm getting this.`Additional information: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Double.`

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add (new SqlParameter("@totalAmount", SqlDbType.Float)).Value =  lblTotalAmount.Text;` I did follow this.

Comment: what is type totalAmount in database ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111746/discussion-between-rai-nalasa-and-abdellah-oumghar).

Answer (score 0):

did you changed the datatype of the field in your DB and it doesnt accept the value? if you dont then you have to....because the datatypes are different